# How to put a picture on the NetBeans main window?

Tags: java, netbeans, ide, customization

Is there a way to put a background image on the NetBeans main window? Is it possible to write a plugin that can make this?

Here is a photo montage of what I want:

[image: Photo montage]

If it is not possible to do: is there any other Java IDE that have this option?

Comment: Intelij idea have this feature but there is no menu to access it. you have to search for 'background' in the shortcut setting to be able set a shortcut and use it.

Answer (score -1):

Try exploring the menu tab Tools>Options>Appearence